# JMeter giving Error percentage in CLI but not in GUI

Tags: java, jmeter, command-line-interface, microservices, latency

I have a small microservice running in a docker container that I am trying to obtain the latency of using JMeter CLI. I made the test using the JMeter GUI and ran the test from it first. And the error percentage then was 0. But when I run the same test using the CLI I get a value for error percentage. And I get the below warnings:

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/jmeter_scripts/factorial.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Tue Feb 18 02:20:35 IST 2020 (1581972635848)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary =     50 in 00:00:02 =   25.0/s Avg:    50 Min:     4 Max:   323 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Tue Feb 18 02:20:38 IST 2020 (1581972638095)
... end of run
2020-02-18 02:20:39,012 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'sampleresult.default.encoding', defaulting to: ISO-8859-1
2020-02-18 02:20:39,022 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'jmeterPlugin.prefixPlugins'
2020-02-18 02:20:39,022 INFO k.a.j.PluginsCMDWorker: Using JMeterPluginsCMD v. N/A
2020-02-18 02:20:39,025 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_LK
2020-02-18 02:20:39,030 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading user properties from: /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/user.properties
2020-02-18 02:20:39,030 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading system properties from: /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/system.properties
2020-02-18 02:20:40,083 WARN o.a.j.g.ObjectTableModel: Header count=13 but classes count=11
2020-02-18 02:20:40,083 WARN o.a.j.g.ObjectTableModel: Header count=13 but writeFunctor count=11
2020-02-18 02:20:40,210 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2020-02-18 02:20:40,215 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2020-02-18 02:20:40,217 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2020-02-18 02:20:40,224 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2020-02-18 02:20:40,224 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2020-02-18 02:20:40,225 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2020-02-18 02:20:40,225 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2020-02-18 02:20:40,226 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-02-18 02:20:40,450 INFO k.a.j.v.AggregateReportGui: Saving CSV to /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/agg_test.csv
```

This is the code that I used to run the test and convert the result to csv:

```
#run test
  cd /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin && sh jmeter -n -t /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/jmeter_scripts/factorial.jmx -l /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/jmeter_results.jtl
  #convert result to csv
  cd /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin && ./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/agg_test.csv --input-jtl /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/jmeter_results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Shown below is the generated aggregated report (using the jtl file). Note that there is an error percentage there.

[image]

Also, note that my JMeter is not inside a container. What am I doing wrong here? How do I not get an error percentage when running in GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see where did you get `a value for error percentage` as it seems to be zero:

> summary =     50 in 00:00:02 =   25.0/s Avg:    50 Min:     4 Max:   323 **Err:     0 (0.00%)**

If you're seeing errors in the generated `/Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/agg_test.csv` it might be the case that the file existed previously and contains "old" results with failures.

Moreover I think you're writing something into that file using [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener and later on appending the last results into the same file using JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool.

In order to get "clean" and valid results:

1. Remove `/Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/agg_test.csv` file
2. Remove `/Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/jmeter_results.jtl` file
3. Remove Aggregate Report listener (and all other listeners) from your Test Plan as [listeners don't add any value and only consume resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/)
4. Repeat your 2 commands in the terminal
5. You should see the `agg_test.csv` file without any errors

Comment: even though it says 0.00% error in the CLI when I generate the aggregate report CSV from the jtl it has an error percentage. I edited the question and included an image of the generated aggregated report.

Comment: Dear, you're not reading (or not able to understand) what I'm saying. Your summary report says that there were **50** samples and in the aggregate report you're showing `40929`. Once you will be able to figure out where do these 40879 extra results come from you will find the source of the errors.